Given $4$-coloring decide $3$-colorability in $P$?
Input: a valid $4$ coloring of graph $G$
output: accept iff $G$ is $3$ colorable
Can this be done in polynomial time ?

I cannot reduce $3$ coloring to this problem (this requires us to find a $4$ coloring which shouldn't be easier) so I believe this's in $P$.
We may try to replace a color $i$ with exactly $1$ other color but when this method fails, it doesn't  mean that there's no $3$-coloring.

Note that the mistake in your presumptions comes when you implicitly say 'finding a 4-coloring shouldn't be easier than finding a 3-coloring'; as D.W.'s answer shows, finding a 4-coloring is much easier than finding a 3-coloring, and this makes sense; you have more options and so more degrees of freedom to work with in trying to find a coloring. The ultimate expression of this is that coloring an n-node graph with n colors is trivial.

No.  3-coloring is known to be NP-complete for planar graphs.  It is known that every planar graph is 4-colorable, and moreover a 4-coloring can be computed in polynomial time.  Therefore, your problem is NP-hard.
In particular, if there were a polynomial-time algorithm $A$ for your problem, then we could take any planar graph $G$, find a 4-coloring (which can be done in polynomial time), apply algorithm $A$, and obtain a 3-coloring of $G$.  This would yield a polynomial-time algorithm for 3-coloring any planar graph, and thus a proof that P=NP.  Therefore, if P!=NP, there is no polynomial-time algorithm for your problem.
